# Error trying to multiply a traingle in javascript

Tags: javascript

Everything works good and proper till I put in this for loop, then I am getting the error sun is not defined.

```
Sun.prototype.TriangleOne = function(pContext) {
    for (var i = 0, i < 12; i++) {
        pContext.save();

        pContext.translate(this.getX() - 80, this.getY());
        pContext.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
        this.Triangle(pContext);
        pContext.restore();
    }
}

function draw() {
    context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < houses.length; i += 1) {
        houses[i].draw(context);
    }

    sun.draw(context);
}
```

Comment: You never declare a variable `sun.`

Comment: Most likely because sun is not defined.

Comment: presuming `Sun.prototype.TriangleOne` is some sort of library you're pulling from, it should be more like so: `Sun.prototype.TriangleOne sun = function(pContext) {`

Comment: @user2366842 that's gonna throw a syntax error.

Comment: @user2366842: I'd assume he just needs something as simple as `var sun = new Sun();`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

`Sun.draw(context);`  maybe you have typo error